# In Place Autocomplete, I found can't load search results try again error

Tags: android, google-places-api

I enabled `Google Places Api`. It works sometimes but not properly. Please suggest me some solution.

It showing:

> Can't load search results, try again.

Comment: Have you enabled billing for google service? As per updated google's policy, we must have to configure billing first before use any library.

Comment: yes i enabled billing account

Comment: How is your Internet connection?